# Use different approach than inner_join

Tags: r

I would like to use another resolution approach that is faster to calculate the `SPV`. See that I use `inner_join`, which is a function that takes considerable computational time, so there is another way to calculate the `SPV`, other than `inner_join` and make it faster.?

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)

df1 <- structure(
  list(date1= c("2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28",
                "2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28"),
       date2 = c("2021-06-25","2021-06-25","2021-06-27","2021-07-07","2021-07-07","2021-07-09","2021-07-09","2021-07-09"),
       Code = c("FDE","ABC","ABC","ABC","CDE","FGE","ABC","CDE"),
       Week= c("Wednesday","Wednesday","Friday","Wednesday","Wednesday","Friday","Friday","Friday"),
       DR1 = c(4,1,4,3,3,4,3,5),
       DR01 = c(4,1,4,3,3,4,3,6), DR02= c(4,2,6,7,3,2,7,4),DR03= c(9,5,4,3,3,2,1,5),
       DR04 = c(5,4,3,3,6,2,1,9),DR05 = c(5,4,5,3,6,2,1,9),
       DR06 = c(2,4,3,3,5,6,7,8),DR07 = c(2,5,4,4,9,4,7,8),
       DR08 = c(0,0,0,1,2,0,0,0),DR09 = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),DR010 = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),DR011 = c(4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0), 
       DR012 = c(0,0,0,3,0,0,0,5),DR013 = c(0,0,1,0,0,0,2,0),DR014 = c(0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0)),
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))

selection = startsWith(names(df1), "DRM")

df1[selection][is.na(df1[selection])] = 0

dt1 <- as.data.table(df1)

cols <- grep("^DR0", colnames(dt1), value = TRUE)

medi_ana <- 
  dt1[, (paste0(cols, "_PV")) := DR1 - .SD, .SDcols = cols
  ][, lapply(.SD, median), by = .(Code, Week), .SDcols = paste0(cols, "_PV") ]


SPV<-df1%>%
  inner_join(medi_ana, by = c('Code', 'Week')) %>%
  mutate(across(matches("^DR0\\d+$"), ~.x + 
                  get(paste0(cur_column(), '_PV')),
                .names = '{col}_{col}_PV')) %>%
  select(date1:Week, DR01_DR01_PV:last_col())%>%
  data.frame()

> SPV
       date1      date2 Code      Week DR01_DR01_PV DR02_DR02_PV DR03_DR03_PV DR04_DR04_PV DR05_DR05_PV DR06_DR06_PV DR07_DR07_PV
1 2021-06-28 2021-06-25  FDE Wednesday            4          4.0            4          4.0          4.0          4.0          4.0
2 2021-06-28 2021-06-25  ABC Wednesday            1         -0.5            3          2.5          2.5          2.5          2.5
3 2021-06-28 2021-06-27  ABC    Friday            4          3.0            5          4.5          5.5          1.5          2.0
4 2021-06-28 2021-07-07  ABC Wednesday            3          4.5            1          1.5          1.5          1.5          1.5
5 2021-06-28 2021-07-07  CDE Wednesday            3          3.0            3          3.0          3.0          3.0          3.0
6 2021-06-28 2021-07-09  FGE    Friday            4          4.0            4          4.0          4.0          4.0          4.0
7 2021-06-28 2021-07-09  ABC    Friday            3          4.0            2          2.5          1.5          5.5          5.0
8 2021-06-28 2021-07-09  CDE    Friday            5          5.0            5          5.0          5.0          5.0          5.0
  DR08_DR08_PV DR09_DR09_PV DR010_DR010_PV DR011_DR011_PV DR012_DR012_PV DR013_DR013_PV DR014_DR014_PV
1          4.0          4.0            4.0            4.0            4.0              4            4.0
2          1.5          2.0            2.0            2.0            0.5              2            2.0
3          3.5          3.5            3.5            3.5            3.5              3            3.5
4          2.5          2.0            2.0            2.0            3.5              2            2.0
5          3.0          3.0            3.0            3.0            3.0              3            3.0
6          4.0          4.0            4.0            4.0            4.0              4            4.0
7          3.5          3.5            3.5            3.5            3.5              4            3.5
8          5.0          5.0            5.0            5.0            5.0              5            5.0
```

Comment: You may use data.table join which could be fast or with `match`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we are using `data.table`, `data.table` join could be faster

```
library(data.table)
f1 <- function(nm, pat) grep(pat, nm, value = TRUE)
nm1 <- f1(names(df1), "^DR0\\d+$")
nm2 <- f1(names(medi_ana), "_PV")
nm3 <- paste0("i.", nm2)
setDT(df1)[medi_ana,  (nm2) := Map(`+`, mget(nm1), mget(nm3)), on = .(Code, Week)]
SPV2 <- df1[, c('date1', 'date2', 'Code', 'Week', nm2), with = FALSE]
```

Comment: thanks for reply. `setDT(df1)[medi_ana,  (nm2) := Map(`+`, mget(nm1), mget(nm3)), on = .(Code, Week)]`is the same as `SPV`? Therefore, `SPV<-setDT(df1),...`?

Comment: @JVieira The `:=` creates the columns in the original data 'df1'.  If you want the 'df1' to be different.  You can do `SPV <- copy(df1); setDT(SPV)[medi_ana,  (nm2) := Map(`+`, mget(nm1), mget(nm3)), on = .(Code, Week)]`

Comment: akrun, this way you did it, I got a different output table than the question's output table. Or I could be doing something wrong.

Comment: @JVieira it is just the column names in your inner_join getting duplicated names ie. `DR03_DR03_P`.  Here, it is `DR03_P`.  It is due the the incorrect use of `.names` in your code

Comment: @JVieira you are also removing some columns with `select`

Comment: I understand now. In your code can you adjust just to select the `DR` columns that end with `PV`? for me to generate an output table equal to the one in the question.

Comment: @JVieira i updated. `> dim(SPV)#
[1]  8 18
> dim(SPV2)#
[1]  8 18`

Comment: Thanks akrun for the help! Just a question, can I use ` bench::mark` to calculate computational time both ways? That is, what did I do and you?

Comment: @JVieira You can use that as well, but with data.table, we are assinging in place, so if we are not using original data in each iteration, it wouldn't be helpful.  You can get some info with `system.time`